# possibility of oil entry into coolant tank of figo

Tags: coolant

What are  the possibilities of oil entering into coolant tank ? how to know it withoout seeing tank ? what need to be checked ? what precautions to be taken not reoccur the same trouble

kishore

Answer (score 1):

If coolant and oil are mixing, it generally means one of three things:

1) blown head gasket
2) cracked head
3) cracked block

You can check the oil dipstick to see if they are mixing. If so, the oil will appear milky and smell a bit sweeter than normal oil. You can also examine the coolant in the overflow tank. It will also be milky and not the normal proper green or reddish-orange color (depending on whether your car requires standard antifreeze, which is green, or dexcool, which is the orange color). It will also be milky, oily, and have a different smell. If you have no coolant in the overflow tank, then you definitely have a problem with coolant being lost (possibly burned off), and should have your car repaired straight away. Even when cold, there should be some coolant in the overflow tank. There should be lines on the tank marking what the level should be for minimum cold, and maximum hot.

Comment: You can have an engine oil cooler, cooled by the engine coolant on the Ford Figo. When they have the CVT transmission, they can also have a trans oil cooler. Both can 'mix' on any failure. You amy also have red antifreeze. Points to watch as well as 'dobey's illustration.